# Gradient with effect of 3d Container in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

How to decorate container like this effect . I tried to use gradient but I don't know how to make horizontal gradient like in the picture .
any help or resources are much appreciated.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Container(
        height: 100,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            colors: [
              Colors.black,
              Colors.purple,
              Colors.blue,
              Colors.green,
              Colors.brown,
            ],
            begin: Alignment.topCenter,
            end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            stops: [0.01, 0.3, 0.4, 0.8, 1],
          ),
        ),
      )
```

You have colors already, you must create `stops` which is self-explanatory in my example and must have equal length to colors.

If you want to make it horizontal, tune `begin` and `end` parameters.